# Swift Delay Problems

Tags: swift, xcode, delay

So i've been working on creating an app where if you press on a button, it triggers *startGame*. This should then wait the delays that I created before changing each image. The delays work, but they start as soon as i launch the app, not when i press the button. Ive been trying to fix it since. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Here is what i think is the more important code:

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
let deadlineTime2 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)
let deadlineTime3 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
let deadlineTime4 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(4)

@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        trumpImage.isHidden = false

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {

            self.trumpImage.image = UIImage(named: "trumpTurnOne")

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime2) {

            self.trumpImage.image = UIImage(named: "trumpTurnTwo")

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime3) {

            self.trumpImage.image = UIImage(named: "trumpTurnThree")

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime4) {

                self.runGame()

        }

}
```

Comment: Is this code inside of a class? It should be inside of your View Controller. Also, make sure you've connected this method to your button via interface builder.

Comment: I've done both of those things, just didn't show all of the code

Comment: Okay, well it'll be easier to answer if you show more code. Your dispatch time variables should also be inside of the IBAction, otherwise they'll be initialized right as the controller loads, though that shouldn't trigger your function. You don't have any explicit calls to `startGame` anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let deadlineTime = {return DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)}
let deadlineTime2 = {return DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)}
let deadlineTime3 = {return DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)}
let deadlineTime4 = {return DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(4)}
```

If you have declared the four `DispatchTime`s as instance properties, the evaluation of initial value is made when the instance is generated, not the time when those properties are actually used. Which means `DispatchTime.now()` represents the time of instantiation, it may be far earlier than user presses the button.

Thus, to make `DispatchTime.now()` represent the time of pressing the button, you may need to make them computed properties. Or else, you need to make them local variables.

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
    let deadlineTime2 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)
    let deadlineTime3 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
    let deadlineTime4 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(4)

    //...
}
```

Comment: Lol can't try right now but i can later ill get back to you guys